# What is a Pseudo Derivative controller

Tags: control-system, pid-controller

Can anyone tell me why the control system designers do not prefer `pure derivative controller`? Instead they use something called a `Pseudo derivative controller`. What is this `Pseudo derivative controller` and how does it has an edge over the `pure derivative controller`?

Comment: By the way, I'm not sure how common the desire or need to avoid a directly expressed derivative term actually is (other than the roll-off pole to cut noise, as noted in the other answer). It is a nice trick to have at your disposal just the same.

Answer (score 2):

Because ideal derivative operation is not causal. For example if you want to calculate the derivative of a function at the point a, you actually need to use the value of that function at a very small time after the point a. As depicted [here](https://calcworkshop.com/derivatives/limit-definition-of-derivative/):

[image]

For example, this is the s-domain representation of a simple PD Controller:

$$ G(s) = K * (s + 3) $$

One of the first things we've learnt while stuyding s-domain representations is, the fact that in order for a system to be causal; the degree of the numerator must not be greater than the denominator's degree. As you can see, the system above is non-causal; since the numerator degree is 1, whereas the denominator 0.

What you can do in that kind of situation is to, add a `low-pass filter` by simply adding a pole which is located at the far left-side plane. Such as:

$$ G(s) = \frac{K * (s + 3)} {s + 40} $$

If you try to implement a derivative operation in a controller, you are probably going to experience some oscillations which are caused by the derivative action. When designing real-control systems, I use `Backward Difference` to make sure to be causal.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of a controller, pseudo-derivative was a term coined by Phelan in the 1970s, e.g. [Phelan 1971](https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/4711540). He made some perhaps excessive claims about it and it was not well received.

In its simplest version, it is an alternative to PI. Two changes are made:  First the zero is moved into the feedback path, which I won't discuss to keep this answer short.

Second is a loop rearrangement, which I sketched below, with P being the plant.
[image: pdf-loop]

The loop on top is the final form giving the pseudo-derivative its name. Note there is no actual derivative. The loop on the bottom is the small-signal equivalent, with the derivative appearing explicitly.

The similarity to a PI controller \$\frac{K}{s}(1+{T_0}s)\$, should be visible. The loop gain, stability, and disturbance rejection are the same as the corresponding PI, but the PI has a closed-loop zero that does not appear in the corresponding PDF.

The closed-loop response of the PDF is also small-signal-equivalent to the corresponding PI, with an additional LPF \$1/(1+{T_0}s)\$ on the input.

---

If you look, you can also recognize this in a modern incarnation, in controllers like Messner's CPIL (Complex PI-Lead) or CPISL (Complex PI-Super-Lead), where the author refers to the same loop-rearrangement as the "parallel inner loop form".